# im trying make a function to auto correct posts when i open the posts in the backoffice

Tags: posts, functions

I have a area where users can submit posts however the posts usually contain a lot of errors and i'm trying to create a function that auto-corrects this errors when I open the post in the back office, it doesn't work:

```
function processpost( $processpost) {

 $errors = array("oly");
 $processpost['post_content'] = str_replace($errors, 'only',$processpost['post_content']);

  return $processpost;
}

add_action('pre_post_update', 'processpost', 99);
```

Comment: Errm... your `add_action` call is _inside_ your function.

Comment: sorry copy pasted it wrong, in functions.php its outside the function.

Comment: Have you tried `$errors = 'oly';` instead of the array?

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, you're using the wrong action - you need:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'processpost' );
```

[View `wp_insert_post` source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#source)